# Go mod replace and github forks of /vN repositories

Tags: go

I've just sent a [pull request](https://github.com/periph/devices/pull/14) to http://periph.io/x/devices/v3; it's already been merged, but something about the process was suboptimal:

First I cloned the repository (which is actually http://github.com/periph/devices; the module is named `periph.io/x/devices/v3` though), so my fork is automatically called http://github.com/lutzky/devices. I wanted to test a separate piece of code I'm working on with the modified library, call it `testclient`; adding this to `testclient/go.mod` works:

```
replace periph.io/x/devices/v3 v3.6.9 => ../devices
```

However, this should also work (and would be useful if the pull request took longer to be accepted), and doesn't:

```
replace periph.io/x/devices/v3 v3.6.9 => github.com/lutzky/devices main
```

That gives this error:

```
testclient/go.mod:15: replace github.com/lutzky/devices:
  version "v0.0.0-20210508194004-cae0146d8900" invalid:
  go.mod has post-v0 module path "periph.io/x/devices/v3" at revision cae0146d8900
```

On a hunch, I figured I'd create a tag `v3.6.9-newfeature` and push that to my fork, and point the `replace` command at that. That doesn't work either:

```
testclient/go.mod:15: replace github.com/lutzky/devices:
version "v3.6.9-newfeature" invalid:
module contains a go.mod file, so major version must be compatible: should be v0 or v1, not v3
```

So I can't use a v0 tag because `go.mod` says it's `v3`, but I can't use a v3 tag because the URL doesn't have `/v3`. I don't *think* I should modify `go.mod` in my forked repository (for one thing, that'd make the pull request silly). What's the intended way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fix that you are looking for, I tested the following `go.mod` file and it works,

```
module test

go 1.14

replace periph.io/x/devices/v3 => github.com/lutzky/devices/v3 v3.6.9-newfeature

require (
    periph.io/x/devices/v3 v3.6.9 // indirect
)
```

I first installed `periph.io/x/devices/v3`,
`go get periph.io/x/devices/v3`

Then I inserted the replace in `go.mod`,
`replace periph.io/x/devices/v3 => github.com/lutzky/devices/v3 main`
Format: `replace <original_module> => <forked_repo> <branch>`

Then I ran just `go get`. After that, the `main` in the replace instruction got  swapped with `v3.6.9-newfeature` which is the latest tag on the forked repo's `main` branch, thus giving you the content that you see above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ramaraja-ramanujan@'s answer and a bit more debugging, I found the answer.

TL;DR - the correct answer is:

```
replace periph.io/x/devices/v3 v3.6.9 => github.com/lutzky/devices/v3 main
                                         // this part was missing ^^^
```

This will work immediately when building, and `go mod tidy` (or `go get`) will change `main` to a specific tag. There are a couple of interesting side-notes to this:

## The go proxy

The `v3.6.9-newfeature` tag was my own; I had created it as part of trying to get this to work. I've deleted it, and yet `go mod tidy` kept replacing `main` with `v3.6.9-newfeature` - no matter how many caches I cleared! Running `strace` it turned out that `go` was contacting http://proxy.golang.org. To disable this, I ran `GOPROXY=direct go get`. This replaced the line with the [pseudo version](https://golang.org/ref/mod#pseudo-versions) `v3.6.10-0.20210508194004-cae0146d8900`. Note that this matches the current `main` commit in my fork, and neither my fork nor the original repo have `v3.6.10` - it appears to have started with the existing `v3.6.9` and incremented it.

## The `/v3` is not a subdirectory

Indeed, the source repo (https://github.com/periph/devices) does not have a `v3` subdirectory. I *thought* what was going on is that the `periph.io` domain is doing some trickery - indeed going to http://periph.io/x/devices/v3 with a browser does work. However, it would appear that Go's resolution takes the final `/v3` in the module path not to indicate, in this case, a subdirectory (but indeed a restriction on tag names). This is apparently allowed, and is discussed in https://golang.org/ref/mod, but it isn't entirely straightforward.